# Count number of open windows in SDL2

Tags: window, sdl-2

I am assuming that in the SDL2 internals, it should have some structure that keeps track of all the existing windows in a program. Is it possible to get the existing windows (or at least a count of the existing, open ones) in SDL2?

Comment: Why can't count it when you create the windows..?

Comment: @Aram yes I can do that, and I will probably end up doing that, but I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way via SDL's interface.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no direct way, you could use the method GetWindowFromID from 0 to max(int32) and check for non NULL results.. but is not elegant (or efficient) at all. Or you could try adding a function yourself to SDL, your function could be like GetWindowFromID https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/7779507bbb82ee59467dc7f15f9d0a8f66988211/src/video/SDL_video.c#L1644 but instead of returning when you find the id you could add to a counter until you get to the end of the linked list and then return that.

Comment: @Aram yes, the checking windowID from 0 to max(uint32) also crossed my mind, but I discarded that idea quickly. Adding a function to the SDL framework will be an interesting exercise I guess, but I would like to make my software as portable as possible (without interfering with the host PC's SDL distribution). I am actually thinking of just creating a base class from which all my other classes that makes SDL windows, inherits from, then make a static `window_counter` variable in the base class which I increment each time a window gets created. Seems like the most elegant solution to me.